# In Qt6 cin/getline does not read any input for me

Tags: c++, qt, newline, cin, qt6

I am just starting with QT6 (and with QT in general).

I have tried to do simpe cin/cout operations and it's already troublesome.
Somehow cin does not read a line, nor does getline.

Here is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void do_something()
{
    string name = "";
    cout << "Enter your name: \n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name << "\n";
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    do_something();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The line "Enter your name: " get's written, the newline character does not!?
Then whatever i type in the console, does not do anything to cin, and the program is, as it seems stuck in cin.

If instead of "\n" i use "endl" for the "\n" at the second cout, the following happens.
Cin is completely getting ignored and the "Hello" also gets printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was, as written in the comments:

1. Run the program in the Terminal, not in the QT Creator's Output Termina.
   In the **output** Terminal you cannot type any input.
2. Flush the buffer because the text lies in the buffer until a endl or a flush occurs.